# TST10 script is giving error: the handle is invalid

Tags: telnet

i am trying to connect to a remote machine(Windows) using TST10 script.i have the VPN access to that machine. i want to automate the telnet session using the TST10 script, kinldy help.

my code is:

```
xx.x.xxx.xx
WAIT "login:"
SEND "domain\username\m"
WAIT "password:"
SEND "VPNpassword\m"
WAIT ">"
SEND "command 1\m"
WAIT ">"
SEND "command 2\m"
```

Here the "username" is the VPN username and not the user account name on the remote machine and "domain" is different from my computer's domain.

If i am telnetting manually from my command prompt with the same VPN credentials, it is working.
But, using the script, i am getting an error : the handle is invalid.

Do i need to give the credentials of the user account in the script or these VPN credentials can also work.

Also, please tell me the reason why i am able to do it manually and why not using the script.

Answer (score 0):

you need a double backslash between your domain and username:

xx.x.xxx.xx
WAIT "login:"
SEND "domain\\username\m"